# Python MSSQL PyODBC with fast_executemany failing

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm having an issue pushing data to an MSSQL table using pyodbc and fastexecutemany.

I've scoured the internet and other posts on Stackoverflow.  As far as I can tell I'm doing this right but am not having a successful load.

I have a straightforward dataframe I'm trying to push.  It looks like this:

```
Date            A      B     C     D

2018-01-03      2.0    1.0   1.0   Joe
2018-01-04      2.0    1.0   2.0   Joe
2018-01-05      2.0    3.0   1.0   Pete
2018-01-06      2.0    1.0   5.0   Mary
...
```

The date is a datetime.  The numbers are floats.  The names are strings

I am trying to load to a Microsoft SQL 2016 database

Here is the code:

```
conn = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.123.45;DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=xx;PWD=yyyyy'
quoted = quote_plus(conn)
new_con = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted)
engine = create_engine(new_con)

@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
    print("FUNC call")
    if executemany:
        cursor.fast_executemany = True

df.to_sql(name=table, con=engine, if_exists=action, index=False, chunksize=None)
```

I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY010', u'[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLParamData)')
```

I have some null values in the data set.  I have changed them to `None` and also to strings (`'NA'`).  No luck.

If I remove the decorator and function to turn on execute many it executes properly but is slow given that it is using Pandas `to_sql`.

Does anyone have insight?

Thanks.

Using:

Windows 10 Professional
Anaconda Python 2.7
PyODBC 4.0.25

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with Python 2.7.14, pyodbc 4.0.25, SQLAlchemy 1.2.17, and pandas 0.24.1. My [test code](https://pastebin.com/AtmjQXdu) works fine. Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Will do.  Thanks.  I suspect it is something in the formatting of the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The table name parameter in 'to_sql' is case sensitive. I wasted a long time on this just because i used to not use case sensitive in sql server.